How do scale down statefulset when it's spread between nodepools?
I have statefulset which is deployed accross 2 different nodepools in AKS. I have total of 4 replicas, 1 on nodepool1 and 3 on nodepool2. I need only 3 to be on nodepool2 and scale it down to just 3 replicas. Is it possible to do? I tried manually to cordon and drain ones on nodepool1 but statefulset refuses to scale down since pod0 is on nodepool1 and refuses to drained from there.
See picture below what happened when I put a taint on nodepool1 to prevent replica from running there but pod refused to be evicted


Is this a one time scaling operation? or you need this as a long term solution?

Could you try to taint nodepool1? it should prevent new pods from being scheduled. Update the StatefulSet to include a nodeAffinity rule to target only nodepool2. Manually evict pods from nodepool1 and adjust the replica count i.e scale it down to 3. Now check using kubectl get pods -o wide I think what you are asking will work like this, later if and when you want nodepool1 just untaint it.

Tried all those, none worked, see image above.

Label nodes in your node pools:
NodePool1: nodepool=nodepool1
NodePool2: nodepool=nodepool2

Update the StatefulSet to add affinity to force Pods to run only on nodepool2.
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
              - matchExpressions:
                  - key: nodepool
                    operator: In
                    values:
                      - nodepool2



If you have a StatefulSet deployed across two node pools (nodepool1 and nodepool2) in your aks cluster

and you want to scale it down to 3 replicas, you can taint nodepool1's nodes to prevent any pods from being scheduled on it.
kubectl taint nodes <node-name> nodepool=nodepool1:NoSchedule


Edit your Stateful Set yaml to include a nodeAffinity rule to ensure all pods are rescheduled to nodepool2.
affinity:
  nodeAffinity:
    requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: agentpool
          operator: In
          values:
          - nodepool2


Cordon the drain the nodes to prevent new pods from being scheduled
kubectl cordon <node-name>



Once all pods are running on nodepool2, scale down the StatefulSet to 3 replicas
kubectl scale statefulset <statefulset-name> --replicas=3

Verify the pods now, it should show 3 replicas and all on nodepool2
kubectl get pods -o wide


StatefulSets do not delete PersistentVolumeClaims (PVCs) for scaled-down replicas automatically so you gotta delete those yourself and then check
kubectl get pvc

looks good

Relevant MS docs-

Resize node pools in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)
Manually scale the node count in an Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster


I tried that but problem is that pod which was on nodepool1 was first pod which was deployed of statefulset and hence was named pod0, and when scaling happened it was stucking in pending even though taint was placed on nodepool1 to prevent node from runing there, evicting it from nodepool1 did not do any good, it just stuck there in pending state. Please see updated original question what it looks like.

will look into it and share with you my findings
